# create POM with junit 4

Tags: maven-3, junit4, pom.xml, maven-archetype

I use Maven 3.0.4 and want to have junit 4 by default.

My projects are created with the command :
**$>mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=my.group.id -DartifactId=myArtifactId -DpackageName=my.package.name**
This puts a depency to junit version 3.8.1 in the created pom.xml, dispite the fact that verion 4.8.1 is already present.
There are no dependencies to junit in my global settings.xml, and I haven't a local .m2/repository/settings.xml. I don't want to remove the old version 3.8.1., but want that all new projects are created with version 4.8.1
Can I do this in my settings.xml (global or local does not matter)? And if so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things:

`archetype:create` is deprecated by `archetype:generate`; please use `generate`, it's interchangeable with `create` in your example.

As for a solution, I'd say the simplest thing to do is generate your project, edit the pom to have the correct `junit` version; and then from within your project run:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

Which will create an archetype based on your modifications, you simply need to install this with:

```
cd target/generated-sources/archetype/
mvn install
```

Now you can create new maven projects with this new archetype as you like with:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=my.group.id -DartifactId=newArtifact -DpackageName=my.package.name -DarchetypeArtifactId=myArtifactId-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=my.group.id
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Add a first glance rather complex, but it will have reasons.

Comment: @Anew how to import/use newly created archetype to eclipse?

Comment: First just tell eclipse where is located your local catalog file. In eclipse : Window => Preference => Maven =>  Archetypes => 'Add Local Catalog'. The default is $HOME/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml. Apply and it should be visible when you create a new maven project/module. Beware of snapshot versions; maybe you have to check 'include snapshot archetype'.

Comment: It seems doesn't work for me because it still try to find it online. Any solutions? Thanks.