# how to configure maven to add junit 4.10 instead of 3.8 dependency in new project

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, maven-3, eclipse-kepler

When i am creating a new maven project in eclipse kepler, eclipse automatically adds junit 3.8 dependency in pom.xml like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to be available newer version like: 4.10,

**Where can i configure to use newer version instead of old?**

Comment: Get a newer version of Eclipse?

Comment: Kepler is the latest.

Comment: @adarshr I am using eclipse kepler service pack 1, i think this version is the latest.

Comment: why not to change the dependency version manually? from 3.8 to desired version.

Comment: @jelies instead of changing manually by me, i want to do that for me by eclipse.

Comment: @Rembo oh I see. An option could be create the new maven project based on an archetype that uses this junit version.

Comment: Windows->Preferences->Maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create POM with junit 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505377/create-pom-with-junit-4)

Comment: @frant.hartm the solution i have to use command prompt, am looking for solution using eclipse new maven project wizard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The junit version is described in archetype that is used to create maven project.

You need to either find archetype that will fit your needs, or create [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505377/create-pom-with-junit-4).

Then once you have it you need to select to use this archetype when [creating the project in Eclipse](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating.html#creating-sect-m2e-create-archetype).

Comment: @frant.hartm Why even now the default JUnit version in Eclipse Maven archetype is 3, not 4 whcih seems to be current?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty common to have a company/product wide version of one of the following: -

- A common parent pom with a dependency management section controlling all your versions
- A common pom which is included as a dependency and imports all the testing dependencies, e.g., my-company-test. That can either include your common test code as well or be of type `pom` and just act as a dependency vacuum.
- An archetype (as frant.hartm says) which defines all of your common dependency versions up front.

I would personally go with both the dependency based pom and an archetype which imports it.

You can always override versions if you need too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to state the `version` that you want in the dependency, for example I use JUnit 4.11 in Eclipse Juno:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.11</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So you need to set your `version` to 4.10 or whatever version there is that you desire.