# Maven - Change jUnit Version in Quickstart Archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I am trying to create a new maven project using the `maven-archetype-quickstart` archetype, which incorporates a `AppTest.java` sample test class and a dependency for Junit version 3.8.1 but I would like to use Junit 4.

How can I change Junit version on the quickstart maven archetype?

Comment: I figured I wasn't the only person in the world who thought this must have done by someone else already. Did you find a different maven archetype out there on central with JUnit4? I would also like it to specify Java 8 in the `maven-compiler-plugin` config.

Answer (score 1):

Use the prompt or a terminal in eclipse and do this :

```
      mvn -B archetype:generate \
     -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
     -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
     -DartifactId=my-app
```

After that you have to import it from Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans as a maven project and you'll got the version of J-Unit 4.X

Comment: I tried this set of commands and then create the project but the results were the same, still includes jUnit 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [other people also had an issue](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-archetype-simple-JUnit-3-8-is-really-old-td5724107.html) with this junit version shipped with maven-archetype-quickstart so they filed a [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MARCHETYPES-41), which was solved in the archetype version 1.2.

Since that version is not in the default [Maven Archetype Catalog](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml), the next task is to find an archetype catalog with the maven-archetype-quickstart 1.2 version and use that catalog for your `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeCatalog=http://your.updated.catalog` command.

**EDIT:** Apparently, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14506202/1138058), you can also create your custom archetype based on a project's POM and then install it in your local archetype catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the version in pom.xml

See this article for in-depth explanation: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/junit-maven-example/

Comment: That is the thing. I want to change the way the archetype is generated, so it automatically adds junit 4 instead of 3.8.1 so I don't have to change the pom.xml every time I create a new project.